# How do I count C64 BASIC score?

Tags: discussion

So I recently posted 2 answers on C64 BASIC.

I first counted it in characters, but after reading more about how the Commodore 64 works, I decided to start counting it in bytes.

But there were already 2 answers before that counted the bytes as characters, not bytes.

Should I use characters, or bytes?

Comment: Years ago, everyone counted characters. Don't let that discourage you.

Comment: C64 BASIC probably uses an SBCS.

Comment: Considering that C64 uses some characters not in <s>Unicode</s> any character set other than its own, I would go with the number of symbols on the screen.